# installing lubuntu on powermac g5 wont boot stuck after starting linux

Tags: system-installation, macintosh, lubuntu

so I'm currently trying to install lubuntu for [mac g5](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/) and am getting the below error

```
i2c i2c-3: i2c-powermac: modalias failure on /u3@0,f8000000/i2c@f8001000/cerea1@1c0
```

what does this error mean and how can I fix it? Also, I'm booting from a firewire enabled hard drive, not sure if that helps. Thanks.

Update: Using driverupdate-powerpc action makes fan speed up in comparison to other actions (live, linux, etc), and ejects the cd drive after error. Does this mean that the linux is still running and is just taking a long time to load?

Comment: What instructions are you following?  What was the exact action on your part that preceded this error?  What have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: The instructions I've followed are http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274612 and the actions I've tried are live and Linux